# ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django

I am making a images' uploas system.
But I got an error,
ValueError at /accounts/upload_save/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' .
I think this error is that int type value is not in argument.

My traceback showed

```
 photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
```

was wrong.
But get() is ok to be in int type value,so I cannot fix my error.
How can I fix it?

I wrote in views.py,

```
@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('profile')


    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)


def photo(request):
    d = {
        'photos': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)


def upload(request, p_id):
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)


def upload_save(request):
    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")
    photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")

    photo_obj.image1 = files[0]
    photo_obj.image2 = files[1]
    photo_obj.image3 = files[2]

    photo_obj.save()

    return redirect("registration/accounts/profile.html")
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,name='regist' ),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<p_id>\d+)/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^upload_save/$', views.upload_save, name='upload_save'),
]
```

in profile.html

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
  {% block content %}

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="ja">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>UPLOAD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    user.username: {{ user.username }}<hr>
    user.is_staff: {{ user.is_staff }}<hr>
    user.is_active: {{ user.is_active }}<hr>
    user.last_login: {{ user.last_login }}<hr>
    user.date_joined: {{ user.date_joined }}

    <div class="container">
      <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")`

**There's no `p_id` in this POST request, therefore `photo_id` is set to an empty string `''`**

`photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)`

Then you try to get an `photo_obj` with this empty string, so it tells you `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: thx,you told me p_id definition is not anywhere,right?
But I think I wrote p_id in views.py
def upload(request, p_id):
    d = {
        'p_id': p_id,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)

So,how can i fix it?

Comment: `p_id` should be one of the parameters in your form, you need to check your profile.html template to make sure this parameter is available.